# HOW TO UPDATE MUTLIPLE COLUMNS IN MS ACCESS USING A SINGLE SQL QUERY

Tags: vb.net

I Have 11 textboxes that successfully loads data into ms access database. A single query updates a single column in a table and terminates the database connection. I added 2 other column of textboxes in my form that i intended to be all loaded into the database with one single button click ie layer1 one of textboxes is updated to the first line/column of the database next line/column is updated by layer2 of textboxes. I already have the code that successfully updates a single column in the database:

```
  'LOADING DATA FROM THE TEXTBOXES TO A DATABASE 
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IEBC ELECTIONS\Database11.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "INSERT INTO BY_ELECTIONS([REFERENCE],[TYPE_OF_ELECTION],[SEAT_CONTESTED],[COUNTY],[GOVERNOR_TRAITS],[SENATOR_TRAITS],[CONSTITUENCY],[MP_TRAITS],[WARD],[MCA_TRAITS],[DATE_OF_ELECTION],[CONFIRMED_BY]) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("REFERENCE", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("TYPE_OF_ELECTION", CType(Textbox2.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("SEAT_CONTESTED", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("COUNTY", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("GOVERNOR_TRAITS", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("SENATOR_TRAITS", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("CONSTITUENCY", CType(TextBox7.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MP_TRAITS", CType(TextBox8.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("WARD", CType(TextBox9.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MCA_TRAITS", CType(TextBox10.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("DATE_OF_ELECTION", CType(TextBox11.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("CONFIRMED_BY", CType(TextBox12.Text, String)))

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I have 24 textboxes. Textbox1 to 12 updates the first column/line of ms access database and Textbox13 to 24 should update the next column/line of the same table. I would love all this to happen with a single button click.
Any advice will highly be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Execute your update with the 1st 12 params as you are doing now, then simply update the value of your params and execute it again.  Also be clear exactly what your asking, in your question your saying "Update", then your code you are doing an "Insert".  Which is it?

Comment: @Hursey, I am sorry about that. I meant insert

Comment: @Hursey from what you said, I get it. But what will happen to the STR and the VALUES(?????????). Will I have to also add question marks of the other 13-24textboxes?